# .Net MVC Web Deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, web-deployment

I have Visutal Studio 2012, MVC 4 & Razor. I am having trouble getting a website up and running with this technology.

The Web Server is a Windows Server 2008 server. I tried deploying using the Web Deploy method but am consistently getting something like 'set ACL" error.

I tried deploying using the File System. All files got deployed, but when I try and run the website, it fails because of missing ASP.NET MVC infrastruccture files.

Two things:
•If I use Web-Deploy, how do I solve the ACL error, because I assume with this method, everything needed will get deployed.

Note that the Web Deploy 3.0 service is on the server and started.
•If I use File System, where can I find the downloads needed to deploy on the server where MVC WILL work. 
◦Note that I downloaded the 4.5 Framework and was successfully installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be more of an IIS issue, but not sure based on the details in your question.
Check that the application pool that the site is running under is using .net 4.0. 
Just a thought I would check.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be a bit more precise with what you need help with.

1. What's the exact error.
2. Often times you need to give the IIS users group access to at least read from the directory where you've deployed.  Did you do this already?
3. Do you have .NET 4.5 and MVC4 installed on the server?  If not, are you expecting those DLLs to be "packaged" with your deployment?  They generally are not since they are "standard" assemblies.  But if you want them to be included in your deployment you can do that by selecting the references in VS and saying "copy."  **This is not recommended** because when you install patches to .NET and MVC on the server, those updates will not carry through to your app, since it'll use the local (old) copies of your assemblies.